# Discord.js bot for one role only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a small discord.js bot I am running on my server that will handle a few custom commands. One of the commands I only want to run for a certain role... I am getting an error that

> Cannot read property 'first' of null

Surely I am missing something obvious here but looking online I am using the same as other people so I am a little confused.

```js
    else if (message.content.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}approve` )
    {
        message.delete();
        const member = message.mentions.roles.first();

        if (member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'DiscordAdmin')) {

        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: In your code, you set the block to only execute if `message.content` is `approve` and nothing more. Role mention returns null because theres no possibility of a role being mentioned and that block executing

Answer (score 0):

Following on Elitezen's points, you cannot get a member from a [Role](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) mention. Instead, use the common `message.mention.members.first` function. Additionally, you are using `.content` instead of `.startsWith`. The issue with this is that the code will only run if the content is "approve". The code below fixes these

```js
// Switch to .startsWith
    else if (message.content.startsWith.toLowerCase() === `${prefix}approve` ) {
        message.delete();
        const member = message.mentions.members.first(); // Member instead of role

        if (member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'DiscordAdmin')) {
          // Run some code
        }
    }
```